# Figure $\infty$ is immersion of circle

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, manifolds

Where can I find prove of:

> Figure $\infty$ is immersion of circle.
>   More thanks for a prove or a function between these manifolds.

Comment: Are you picturing the "$\infty$" figure in a plane?

Comment: @Gustavo Marra :The source says nothing but I suggest in plane.

Comment: Then I believe there's no immersion of a circle into the $\infty$ figure, since you lose injectivity at the self-intersection of "$\infty$". In which book did you see this?

Comment: The statement is correct; there is an injective immersion.

Comment: @EricO.Korman Which one you know prove of existance or the function.

Comment: @EricO.Korman: I think you are overlooking the fact that he takes the figure $\infty$ to be an immersed *circle*. It is the image of an injective immersion of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @HoseynHeydari: This falls under the heading of things Gowers refers to as "Just Do It" proofs. (See http://gowers.wordpress.com/2008/08/16/just-do-it-proofs/) To get you started: what is the definition of an immersion? Can you obtain a figure X as an immersion from the disjoint union of two intervals? OK, now you are done.

Comment: [Lemniscate of Bernulli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate_of_Bernoulli)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An *immersion* of the circle $S^1$ into the plane is tantamount to a periodic function
$$t\mapsto {\bf z}(t)=\bigl(x(t),y(t)\bigr),\qquad {\bf z}(t+2\pi)\equiv{\bf z}(t)$$
with ${\bf z}'(t)\ne{\bf 0}$ for all $t$. At the [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate_of_Bernoulli) given by Yuri Vyatkin we find the following parametric representation of the lemniscate, the "typical" $\infty$-curve:
$$x(t)={a\sqrt{2}\cos t\over 1+\sin^2 t},\quad y(t)={a\sqrt{2}\cos t\sin t\over 1+\sin^2 t}\ ,$$
which is obviously smooth and $2\pi$-periodic. To test this map $t\mapsto{\bf z}(t)$ for regularity   we compute
$$\bigl|{\bf z}'(t)\bigr|^2={2a\sqrt{2}\over 3-\cos(2t)}\ ,$$
and find that this is $>0$ for all $t\in{\mathbb R}$.